# How to add fade out effect after merging two audio files using ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I tried merging two audio files using following command,

```
 executeFfmpeg(`-i voice.wav -i background.wav -t ${duration+2} -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.wav`)
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
          console.log('Merging finished !');
        }).run();
```

But I also want to fade out the audio in the end,
So to do that I tried the following code,

```
  executeFfmpeg(`-i voice.wav -i background.wav -t ${duration+2} -vf "fade=t=out:st=${duration-1}:d=3" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.wav`)
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
          console.log('Merging finished !');
        }).run();
```

But the background audio volume is unchanged.  Working with ffmpeg for the first time. So don't know what's happening. Need help :(

Answer (score 0):

Combined command:

```
executeFfmpeg(`-i voice.wav -i background.wav -filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=longest,afade=t=out:st=${duration-1}:d=1" output.wav`)
```

- Just add to your `-filter_complex` instead of adding a separate `-vf` (`-vf` is for simple filtering of video).
- Use [afade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade), not the fade filter.